# Repeated measurment - dependent variable only at one assessment point

Tags: repeated-measures

I have repeated measures (two assessments) of an independent variable (binomial/two different groups) but dependent variables (continous) measured at only one assessment - what analysis approach would be appropriate?
I checked if there are significant differences regarding those variables between the groups. I also did logistic regression analysis.
But is there another approach which could analyze the relationship between these variables or wether the dependent variables influence the group membership? Would ANOVA or ANCOVA be appropriate?